# Installable .ipa without device info? How to do it?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipa, software-distribution

Someone recently sent me a .ipa file that I was able to install on my iPhone. They didn't have any of my device information, so no registration of my device was done. I am an Apple developer, but pretty sure I just installed the .ipa via iTunes. I guess my device is registered under my developer program with provisioning profiles, etc, but they didn't register it.

What technique did they use for this? Enterprise Program? Or can any developer send an .ipa to another developer and they'll be able to install it without knowing anything about their device?

Would be nice to be able to send .ipa files to clients for testing without having to register their devices.

Comment: Why don't you try asking them what they did?

Comment: Most probably an app signed with an InHouse profile (Enterprise program).

Comment: Was it actually a developer Ad-Hoc release? Development and Ad-Hoc releases have to have your device ID incorporated in the provisioning profile that they built and signed their code with, so that makes me think you received an App Store .ipa that was signed by Apple.

Comment: @Gavin, yeah, well obviously could do that, but my contact there may not even know, he was just passing something along that was built by another team, so don't want to bother them or seem stupid. Really I find it odd that people bother with the Ad Hoc distribution when this seems so much better?

Comment: Seems to me the close/down votes (because it's not about programming...provisioning doesn't count?  how about linking?) are misplaced.  Also, "ask them how they did it" is definitely a non-proramming answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two words: Enterprise Program.

Comment: can you tell me what are the major advantages of the Enterprise Program? thank you

Comment: Yeah, like so why on earth would I try to do the Ad Hoc release and have to get all the devices registered, super bad for sending to clients, when I can use this Enterprise Program. Are there other draw backs to it?

Comment: Marking this one as the answer, as it is probably correct, and was the first one to say it (I had assumed as much in my question details but wasn't sure). But @Cyrille it would be great if you had some info to share on this. Are there any other issues with Enterprise Program, that make it hard to package this way?

Comment: It's not harder than with a classic account. You select your project, Archive it, then Distribute it with the Organizer to generate an IPA. If you have the good signing certificates, which isn't harder compared to classic accounts, it's all smooth.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good guess that the app is provisioned with an [enterprise account](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) identity.  The enterprise account requires a Dun and Bradstreet identity as well as contact info of an officer.  In agreeing to the terms, the developer agrees to distribute apps to employees of that business (and I think to third parties, but exclusively to assist in development or test).